# Revoking a digital signature at the cryptographic level

Tags: cryptography, hash, public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, pgp

How do I indicate that a specific document or transaction associated with a particular signature should no longer be considered valid?

I'm talking of recalling a signed document, not revoking the private key, because with the private key I can sign two documents and I need to recall/invalidate only the one.If revoke the private key, then I invalidate them both.

For instance,let's say as a metaphor that I sign a Check (bank), and after a month I want to cancel that Check, so that I prevent someone who received the Check **before** I invalidated it , to go to the bank **after** I invalidated it and try to cash it out ?

Comment: You cannot revoke the signature itself at the cryptographic level. You could issue a (signed) revocation notice at the application/document level though and mandate that as part of signature validation also the existence of such revocation notice must be checked. That's basically how certificate revocation works.